# python pandas multi-index assignment gives key error

Tags: python, pandas

in a loop, I fill a multi-indexed dataframe with elements using the loc[(x,y)] for indexing. While this works well for some thousand elements, I suddenly get a key-error.

```
# setupt of empty dataframe with multi-index
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((), names=['cycle','itemNr']) 

# adding data elements using loc in a loop like this
df.loc[ (currentCycle, currentItem) , 'a' ] = 99
```

After adding 10000 rows, each with 15 columns, I get a key error.

Am I using the wrong index method?

Do I need to ensure sorted multi-index?

Is there a size limit?

```
df.shape
OUT: (10000, 15)

df.loc[(282,1), 'columnA'] = 99 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-0a92a62250dd> in <module>()
----> 1 df.loc[(282,1), 'columnA'] = 99

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    192             key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
    193         indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
--> 194         self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
    195 
    196     def _has_valid_type(self, k, axis):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
    373                     self.obj.is_copy = None
    374 
--> 375                     nindexer.append(labels.get_loc(key))
    376 
    377                 else:

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py in get_loc(self, key, method)
   2089             key = _values_from_object(key)
   2090             key = tuple(map(_maybe_str_to_time_stamp, key, self.levels))
-> 2091             return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2092 
   2093         # -- partial selection or non-unique index

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.MultiIndexHashEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.MultiIndexHashEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.MultiIndexHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.MultiIndexHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: (282, 1)
```

**How to Reproduce:**

CVS file reproduce_loc_assignment_error.csv http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=61488607596539177759

The file has 10000 lines and just 3 columns (2 index columns and one data column a)

```
df = pd.read_csv('reproduce_loc_assign_error.csv', index_col=[0,1])
df.loc[(282,2),'a'] = 100 #( gives key error)
```

Comment: Can you add the for loop you are using too ?

Comment: I'm adding values form a big data file. I try to reproduce with synthetic data and will post it if I succeed#

Comment: It maybe a bug, assinging with .loc creates new row if index not found. Still curious why you got this error .

Comment: The strange thing is, the loc assignment that gives the key error creates a new row but does leave the column value NaN. It may have to do with that my MultiIndex shows levels 1.0, 2.0, ... rather than 1, 2, 3. E.g. when display tail for df, it shows cycle 282.0 item 0.0. I'm currently not able to reproduce with synthetic data

Comment: when inspecting the index values of the second level, i found that 0.0 is at beginning and end of the list 

df.index.get_level_values(1)
Float64Index([ 0.0,  1.0,  2.0,  3.0,  4.0,  5.0,  6.0,  7.0,  8.0,  9.0,
              ...
              42.0, 43.0, 44.0, 45.0, 46.0, 47.0, 48.0, 49.0, 50.0,  0.0],
             dtype='float64', name='itemNr', length=10000)

Comment: how about setting the df up without an index first? That way you can enter 'cycle' and 'itemNr' as columns, and then `set_index` into a multi-index after you finish setting it up fully

Comment: If I just run the lines you posted and add some random data my index looks slightly different:  Int64Index([0, 1, 1], dtype='int64', name='itemNr'). I have no idea why your index is of type float64 and mine is int64.

Comment: Can you post a part of the code where you fill your data in the df?  maybe the problem is inside the loop.

Comment: I wrote my df to csv to human read it and check if something is unusual. It can be used to reproduce the issue. When I delete a random line from the csv such it has less than 10000 rows, the error does not occur. It seem to have something to do with 10000 rows.